# How to add receipent email in footer email template magento2

Tags: magento2, email, footer, customize

I have created custom footer email template by overriding it from **Marketing >Email Templates**.

I have an requirement where i have to display the recipient email address in the footer every-time in the email.

How to get the recipient email address in the footer email template.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: the recipient email address is the customer email address?

Comment: Hi Khoa , Yes the recipent email address means the customer email address only... In our scenario, we have over-riden the footer email template and we need to display the respective user email address in the footer template.  Let's say for example a user is placed an order and the user will receive the order confirmation email and in that email in the footer need to display the customer email. and also order copy will be send to admin and in that email we need to display the admin email address in the footer.  Feel free to ask me any more queries. Thanks..

Comment: It will always be the (To Email) address and not necessarily be the logged in customer email Id. 

Ex : while running a scheduled job i would be sending email to multiple To Email addresses.

--

Comment: I also facing the same requirement.could you help me out ? Could you share the code to get receipent  email in footer template